# Updating Drush to newer version on Drupalpro VM Virtual Machine Instance

Tags: drush

I'm setting up a new vm box with a fresh copy of Drupalpro and I need to update Drush and I'm not sure how to go about it. Any ideas would be great. The current drush version that is preinstalled is 5.3 drush.

Answer (score 0):

Using a fresh setup of Drupal Pro VM image, all you have to do is just goto the drush directory and do a git pull from there to pull in the latest code from drush's repo. This is what i did:

cd ~/drush

git pull

git checkout 7.x-5.9

You can load up another drush version by just listing out the ones available by doing a **git tag**